# How to download Csv from google trends using javascript apify puppeteer

Tags: csv, download, google-trends, apify

i use that code to download csv from google trends using apify js, but it doesn't work, could you help me?
the result is a csv with a wrong content.
i try to get all csv from google trends.

```
const path = require('path');
const downloadPath1 = path.resolve(__dirname, './downloads');
  
const fs = require('fs');
try{
const util = require('util');
await util.promisify(fs.mkdir)(downloadPath1);  
}
  catch( e){


  }
  
await page.setRequestInterception(true); 
//await page.click(csvSelector);
  await page.waitForSelector(csvSelector)
 const hrefElement = await page.$(csvSelector);
  await hrefElement.click();

const xRequest = await new Promise(resolve => {
  page.on('request', async interceptedRequest => {
            const type = interceptedRequest.resourceType();
            log.info(type)
            if (  type == "xhr" ) {interceptedRequest.abort();
             resolve(interceptedRequest);}
            else interceptedRequest.continue();
        });
});
log.info(xRequest._url);
const request = require('request-promise');
const options = {
    encoding: null,
    method: xRequest._method,
    uri: xRequest._url,
    body: xRequest._postData,
    headers: xRequest._headers
}

/* add the cookies */
const cookies = await page.cookies();
options.headers.Cookie = cookies.map(ck => ck.name + '=' + ck.value).join(';');
const response = await request(options); 

fs.writeFileSync(downloadPath1+'/binary.csv', response);
  

 
const fileObjs = fs.readdirSync(downloadPath1, { withFileTypes: true });
  
console.log("\nCurrent directory files:");
fileObjs.forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});

 
// There won't be more files so let's pick the first
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(downloadPath1+`/${fileObjs[0].name}`);
log.info(fileData);
// Now we can use the data or save it into Key-value store. 

await Apify.setValue('MY-Csv.csv', fileData, { contentType: 'application/csv'});
```

i hope that someone can propose a solution for this  thanks

Comment: Not sure what is the reason to use the fs module here? Can you try to just save the response to KV store directly?

await Apify.setValue('MY-Csv.csv', response.toString(), { contentType: 'text/csv'});

Comment: Thanks, ok, but the problem is the result is wrong, i get this line; ["-1",null,[[["ANDROID_BACKUP",0],["BATTERY_STATS",0],["SMART_SETUP",0],["TRON",0]],-3334737594024971225],[],{"175237375":[10000]}]
which refer to that url:https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true, but me i click on button to download multiTimeline.csv, the problem i have is that the url we get is wong cause it s due to a call to js function when we click on button